# Actionbar Issue

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

I want custome actionbar so i edited `values-v14/style.xml`

Here is what i change in xml file

```
            <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
               <item name="android:height">60dp</item>
            </style>
```

this  is my java code where i enabled drawer icon

```
                    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
                    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
                    getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
```

Now I run on 4.2 and  Up device its fine But when i run 4.1 device it's show back icon not drawer icon any answer must be appreciated.

you can see drawer icon replaced with back [image: button icon]

Hear is image of 4.4.4 Device you can check and please help me 
            [image: in this image is fine]

Comment: Solution <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
       
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar styles -->
    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.ActionBar">
          <item  name="android:height">60dp</item>
         
    </style>

Answer (score 0):

In your style.xml

```
<style name="Theme.mytheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/your_icon</item>
</style>
```

add any icon you want. Icon mostly depends on Device API level.

Comment: i do with your code but now one more problem occur its change home icon and drawer icon is gone.thanks for your suggestion

Comment: ok when i change action bar height in values-v14/style.xml. its working fine with 4.2,4.4 and 5.0 but when  i see 4.1 it drawer button replace home indicator icon  you can see both image on my question 1 image  is 4.1 android,and 2 image is 4.4 and see navigation  drawer display in 4.4 but in 4.1 display home icon

Comment: home up icon and drawer icon is not same thing. HomeUp is provided to give you UP navigation whereas Drawer icon indicates that there is a menu which will open if you tap on Drawer icon.

Comment: Thanks Murtaza Hussain  for your answer i got solution.

Comment: @Satish great. and whats that ?

Comment: Actually I did mistack in style.xml if you want to see  i can show you  updated  style.Xml

Comment: yeah, update your question so other can benefit from it.

Answer (score 0):

Your ask is not clear, however... if i understand, you have an application that runs well on 4.2 devices showing drawer icon on left side (drawer menu navigation i suppose). The same application on 4.1 devices doesn't show drawer icon but back icon.

1. Be sure that your `style.xml` is correct.
2. Note that `values-v11/style.xml` is for API 11+
3. For API 14+ you must use `values-v14/style.xml` is for API 14+

You can try to add a new folder to your project `values-v19/style.xml` for API 19+ Android 4.4
Look in Android Official API Guides -> App Resources -> Style for more details.

And as last I give you two links resources:

1. To create ActionBars: http://jgilfelt.github.com/android-actionbarstylegenerator/
2. Useful tools can be found here: http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/index.html

Comment: When I change height of action bar drawer icon invisible.I need to show drawer icon You understand what i mean?

Comment: Really sorry but i don't see connection between height and icon. If you want show or hide the action bar you can use `show()` `hide()` methods of actiobar. To show drawer icon you must implement Navigation Drawer you can find it here https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html it's a default icon of system from ICE SCREAM 4.0.3 API 15+